# IDC connector in the middle of a ribbon cable

Tags: connector

Say I have a 1 meter long ribbon cable with insulation displacement connectors (IDC) at either end. Can I install another IDC in between at the half meter mark? I am afraid that if the connector blade in the middle cuts the wires along with the insulation electrical contact will be lost between the two end connectors. (The connectors and cables have a 2 mm pitch.)

Comment: In general there should be no problems adding connectors, assuming it is done properly. The classic mistake is when the connector is sloppily attached so that it shorts nearby signals. But I think you need to be more specific, "IDC" could be anything. And the important pitch is probably ribbon cable pitch, which is not necessarily the same as the connector pitch.

Comment: Just keep in mind, that on some types of IDC connectors, you need to pass the cable through the strain relief, which can be difficult if you're adding connector onto an existing cable, so take some time to think about this topic, and if possible try to use a type of connector which doesn't require cable to go through strain relief.

Comment: "The connectors and cables have a 2 mm pitch" BTW most ribbon cables the pitch on the cable is half the pitch of the connectors.

Comment: It's common, but beware of signal integrity problems when you're transmitting digital data. The device at the middle of the cable would experience "reflected-wave switching". The end of the cable should be the preferred location when only one device is attached, as in the case of IDE hard drives. It may or may not be a problem for your application depending on your system's operating frequency.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can: no problem.

The insulation displacement connector doesn't break the wire core. The blades touch the wire core on either side.

[image: Insulation displacement technology]

Source: [IDC Connector: Insulation Displacement Contact](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/connectors/idc-connector-insulation-displacement-contact.php)

Indeed, this is done all the time.

[image: Ribbon cable with multiple IDCs]

Source: [Sweetwater](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/4msMultPwr10P--4ms-multi-power-cable-10-pin)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  This is a typical way to use ribbon cables and IDC connectors.  In fact, when hard disks were connected to their controllers with ribbon cables they (and floppy disks) would be "daisy-chained", with multiple drives per controller.

Answer (score 1):

To analyse your reasoning...

Cutting conductors wouldn't give a good connection. You'd have an intermittent connection at best, with the cut end of the conductor butting up against the blade. The slightest movement of the cable would disconnect it.

Supposing this wasn't a thing though, somehow...

If the blades on an IDC connector could cut the conductors, this would be a problem at the ends of the cable too. It wouldn't matter where the connector is on the cable - the conductor would be cut one side of the connector, and signals wouldn't get down the cable on that side.

If this were the case, then IDC connectors would need an indicator of which is the "good" direction for the cable, where conductors can't be broken. A vital step when assembling IDC cables would be checking that you'd got this direction right.

Of course you'll know that this isn't a thing for IDC connectors - because this isn't how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the answers I received. The problem is solved. I have successfully connected a IDC connector in the middle being confident from the help I received from here. However I used a portable vice to press the connector. There is no cable cut but out of 20 pins pin no 1 has no connection. Remaining pins have connection. Thanks for your help